# JPA 2.2 TemporalType.TIMESTAMP sets query parameter to 00:00:00

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

We have řecently migrated a project from JPA 2 / Hibernate 4 / Java7 -----> JPA 2.2 / Hibernate 5.3.24 Java 11. Our HQL queries have since changed behaviour causing some nasty bugs,

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<CompetitionUser> findUsersToCheckSession(Session session){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("select distinct cu from CompetitionUser cu");
        sb.append(" left join fetch cu.competition c");
        sb.append(" left join fetch cu.user");
        sb.append(" left join fetch cu.currentBestSession as cus");
        sb.append(" left join fetch cus.session");
        sb.append(" where cu.user = :user and cu.leftCompetition = false");
        sb.append(" and ((cu.dateJoined <= :dateStarted and c.nationalComp is null) or (c.dateCreated <= :dateStarted and c.nationalComp is not null))");
        sb.append(" and c.deleted = false and c.archived = false order by c.title");
        Query q = entityManager().createQuery(sb.toString());
        q.setParameter("user", session.getUser());
        q.setParameter("dateStarted", session.getDateStarted(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

When I look at the SQL output the `dateStarted` parameter used to provide the full date and time (eg. '2021-12-17 12:51:02') but now it always sets the time to 00:00:00 (eg. '2021-12-17 00:00:00')

Here is the dateStarted field

```
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_started", nullable = false, length = 29)
    public Date getDateStarted() {
        return this.dateStarted;
    }
```

Has something changed in the spec? We are using java.util.Date within our Entity

Comment: `getDateStarted()` != `getDateSwam()` you sure you are looking at the right fields? Also there is no need to provice the `TemporalType` in `q.setParameter("dateStarted", session.getDateStarted(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);`. Also also, since you are on java 11 now, you should definitely use `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` as types. With these you don't need `@Temporal` annotation.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, copied the wrong Getter, updated now, it has the same annotations

Comment: Yes we will migrate to Java Date/Time API at some point but I didn't want to get stuck into that right now as would require a lot of retesting

Comment: If I remove TemporalType from setParameter it still sets the time to 00:00:00

Comment: Have you tried to move the annotations to the field? AFAIK there might be slight difference how the annotations are handled depending on where they are located. Also I just checked and hibernate 5.2 does not support JPA 2.2 [hibernate website](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.2/) states exactly that. Also hibernate 5.2 already reached its end of life. You should get [compatible versions](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/)

Comment: Actually we are using hibernate 5.3.24.Final - its the versions bundles with JavaEE8 and Wildfly 26 so they are compatible

Comment: You say you only look at the generated SQL parameters. Have you checked the actual value of `session.getDateStarted()`?

Comment: Yes of course, the database field (postgres timestamp) has a time

Comment: Not whats in the database, whats `System.out.println(session.getDateStarted());` giving you?

Comment: The dateStarted getter returns the full date and time, the time is being lost when its being assigned as a query parameter

Comment: The only idea I have left is that it could be that hibernate also looks at what column you compare the parameter to. Meaning `cu.dateJoined` and `c.dateCreated` could be actually just dates and not datetime. Thus hibernate omits the time part. Otherwise perhaps the postgres timestamp mapping which could be an issue. Overall, try to just switch the involved date fields to `LocalDateTime` and see if that would fix it

Comment: Thanks for the input, actually you are right it was the cu.dateJoined field that has TemporalType.DATE, when I change this to TIMESTAMP it works ok. Annoying as I wanted to keep dateJoined as a date only, I guess hibernate is not smart enough to compare the two as different types.

Comment: Feel free to add this as an answer if you want

Comment: If `c.dateCreated` is a timestamp and `cu.dateJoined` is a date, then you can supply the same parameter 2 times with different names. Then it should resolve the timestamps and dates correctly. There should be no difference in results is `cu.dateJoined` is treated as timestamp or date as long as the database only contains date values